# I can't print values of an object in Angular/html script

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I created service and component for listing objects in Angular. And list is working corretcly (I tried with 'console.log()'). But nothing appears when I try to print them in `localhost:4200`.

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let py of list">
    <td>{{py.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

("list" is an object array created with http get)

Also, my html component works fine, so it works when I write simple lines with `<h1></h1>`. And my object is not empty so if I change `{{py.name}}` part to `{{py}}`, I can see `[object Object]` in localhost.
Can you help me to solve my problem?

I'm using vs code as IDE and here is my Angular version and ect:

`Angular CLI: 12.1.1`

`Node: 14.17.3`

`Package Manager: npm 6.14.13`

`OS: win32 x64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're `console.log`ing at a point when the object is undefined.

To see the object's value in the HTML, you can take advantage of the `json` pipe.

Try this in your HTML:

```
<pre>{{ list | json }}</pre>
```

Also, you can't use `*ngFor` for an object I don't think, you usually use `*ngFor` for an array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention but list is an object array.

Comment: I used json and I can see my object's all values. But I need to print only name of the object.

Comment: Ok, your HTML seems fine to just print the name. It doesn't work?

Comment: I solve the problem. Problem was just discrepancy between database column names and angular model variable names. I didn't think about this simple case..